# Resize view height by touch_move

Tags: java, android, resize, touch

I am trying to resize view height. 
I build a little code, based on `MOTION_EVENT.MOVE`

```
resize2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    y = motionEvent.getY();
                }
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    dy = motionEvent.getY();
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(resizeInner2.getLayoutParams().width, resizeInner2.getLayoutParams().height);
                    if (dy > y) {
                        if (params.height >= (HEIGHT * 2)) {
                            params.height = (HEIGHT * 2);
                        } else {
                            params.height += 10;
                        }
                    }

                    if (dy < y) {
                        if (params.height <= HEIGHT) {
                            params.height = HEIGHT;
                        } else {
                            params.height -= 10;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("test", "action move " + resizeInner2.getLayoutParams().height);
                    resizeInner2.setLayoutParams(params);
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

resize2 its my linearLayout bottom border with size 5-15dp. 

resizeInner2 - linearLayout which im resizing

HEIGHT = static int height  (example 300px)
```

This code work good but not awesome.
If using this part on listview or in ScrollView than my resize not working . Can any help me  or show better path how to do it.

Comment: in ListView and ScrollView it intersects move events to scroll. You have to pass them to views somehow